# How to add Div at the page bottom right hand side

Tags: html

I am trying to add Chat Functionality to my website so i wanted to add a Div at the bottom of the right side of the page similarly as shown in this website

http://kopatheme.com/demo/great-blog-free-web-template/

So For this i have taken a sample HTML

This is my complete HTML page

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
        #tawkchat-minified-container {
                margin: 0;
                border: 0 none;
                padding: 0;
                cursor: pointer;
                z-index: 999999;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                width: auto;
                height: auto;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                border: 1px solid #e3e0e7;
                border-bottom: 0;
                -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
                -moz-background-clip: padding;
                background-clip: padding-box;
        }
        .border-corner {
                border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px !important;
                -moz-border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px !important;
                -webkit-border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px !important;
        }
        .theme-background-color {
                background-color: #7fb06f;
        }
        html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, abbr, address, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp, small, strong, sub, sup, var, b, i, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                border: 0;
                outline: 0;
                font-size: 100%;
                vertical-align: baseline;
                background: transparent;
        }
        div {
                display: block;
        }
        p {
                display: block;
                -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
                -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
                -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
                -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
        }
        .theme-text-color {
                color: #ffffff;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tawkchat-minified-container" class="theme-background-color border-corner">
   <div id="tawkchat-status-middle">
      <div id="tawkchat-status-text-container" class="theme-text-color">
         <p id="tawkchat-status-message"><span id="short-message">Offline</span></p>
      </div>
      <div id="tawkchat-minified-agent-container" class="theme-text-color">
         <p id="tawkchat-minified-agent-information-wrapper"></p>
      </div>
      <div id="tawkchat-minified-link-container">
         <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="maximizeChat" title="Maximize">
            <div class="icon"></div>
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and applied the CSS , but when i ran the above HTML nothing related to that is shown .

coud you please tell me how to add similar div to the page ??

https://jsfiddle.net/aarrLL02/

Comment: Are you using any chat plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi now define this css

Define `position` `fixed` not `absolute` and **remove** `top` and `left` `position` only add `bottom`  and `right` as like this

```
#tawkchat-minified-container {
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 200px;
                right: 0;}
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/aarrLL02/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CSS property `position: fixed;` to set the box fix to the bottom of the page.

HTML:

```
<div class="chat">Chat</div>
```

CSS:

```
.chat {
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 20px;
   width: 300px;
   height: 30px;

   color: white;
   background: green;
   padding: 7px 10px;
}
```